# Detect graceful close of boost blocking socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

using read_until:

```
tcp::socket socket(...);
boost::asio::streambuf data;
boost::system::error_code read_until_error;

size_t bytes_found = boost::asio::read_until(
    socket, data, "\n", read_until_error);
```

according to docs [it](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until/overload12.html) doesn't throw and there is a lot of different error codes in [boost::system::errc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp) but which one is socket closed gracefully by peer? There is a conn reset but I think that's different.

Comment: Graceful close is always detected by "receiving" zero bytes.

Comment: It is [EOF from misc_erros](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/error__misc_errors.html), which is described in [read stream requirements](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SyncReadStream.html) - *If all data has been read from the stream, and the stream performed an orderly shutdown, sets ec to stream_errc::eof and returns 0.*.